# Over-enthusiastic smoke detector

Tags: smoke-detectors

The hard-wired smoke detectors in my house all were well beyond their rated expiration. So I replaced them all. I now need to keep a broom handy whenever I use my oven or broiler -- the smoke detector nearest the kitchen area nearly always goes off and must be silenced. I intend to look into getting a more enthusiastic vent hood, but until then, do I have any options? It's not as if I have a cloud of visible smoke billowing out of the stove.

Edit:

- 14 feet from stove to detector
- New model: first alert 9120b
- Previous model: long gone in trash

Comment: Model # of new smoke detectors? How far is the detector from the stove?

Comment: First question: it's at home and I'm away right now. Second question: twelve or fifteen feet in my estimation.

Comment: Since you were happy with the performance of the old units, can you obtain more of that model, or the comparable new version of that model?  Link it and perhaps people can give reco's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [First Alert web page FAQ for this model](https://www.firstalertstore.com/store/products/hardwired-smoke-alarm-9120B.htm):

> Q: What is the proper placement of smoke alarms?
>
> A: It is important that you have the proper placement for your smoke alarms. Install your alarms **at least 20 feet from appliances like furnaces and ovens**, which produce combustion particles. Alarms should be at least 10 feet from high humidity areas like showers and laundry rooms, and at least 3 feet from heat/AC vents. Be sure to install a smoke alarm in each bedroom, one at the top of each stairwell, and one on every level.

Sticking with the same brand for compatibility of hardwired devices (I have no connection to First Alert), you might want to replace that particular device (**only the one near the kitchen**) with:

[First Alert BRK Brands Hardwired 120-Volt AC/DC Heat Alarm with Battery Backup - HD6135FB](https://www.firstalertstore.com/store/products/brk-brands-hardwire-heat-alarm-with-battery-backup-hd6135fb.htm)

> This First Alert HD6135FB Hardwired Heat Alarm is a great add-on for crawl spaces, laundry rooms, garages, bathrooms, **kitchens**, or other applications not suitable for smoke alarm installations. This heat alarm features advanced rate-of-rise sensing technology. The alarm sounds if either the temperature reaches 135 degrees Fahrenheit or if the temperature rises more than 15 degrees Fahrenheit in one minute.

This type of device would not be suitable for replacement of the alarms near bedrooms, as there you really need a smoke alarm (smoke itself can be dangerous, plus you need that extra warning where people might be sleeping). But for a kitchen area this is ideal as it will activate from heat if you have a real fire situation while avoiding nuisance trips from frying, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I deserve a downvote for not thinking of the manufacturer's website as a solution to this problem!