# Combine Lights on one switch and remove smoke detector from switch

Tags: switch, smoke-detectors

Experts,

I've got a weird wiring situation in my kitchen (just bought the house).

"A" (a dimmer) in the picture controls both a light (let's call it light "X") and (wait for it) the smoke detector!

"B" has 2 switches. The bottom controls the garbage disposal, the top controls another light (light "Y").

What I'd like to do is have the switch on "B" that controls light "Y" also control light "X". Then I would simply blank out "A" so that power is always going to the smoke detector.

I have confirmed that both "A" and "B" are on the same circuit.

What is your best advice? Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Brilliant idea for when my wife cooks.  Joking aside, how close to the kitchen is the smoke detector?

Comment: Ha! Not sure that was the intent here (all kinds of weird stuff like this throughout the house), but funny nonetheless.

Comment: If there is another detector on that floor, maybe down the hall a bit, you can probably remove it.

Comment: @GaryBak Unless power is chained from this smoke detector to all the others.

Comment: See my answer https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/153711/over-enthusiastic-smoke-detector/153820#153820 as far as heat detector vs. smoke detector in the kitchen. But in any case you need to get it off of the switch.

Answer (score 1):

Pigtail the wires going to lights A and B together with a short 6" wire, and send that to the pole of your new switch, and supply the other pole with hot from the breaker.

Send the wire going to the garbage disposal to a pole on your other switch, and supply the other pole with hot from the breaker.

Then just send hot from the breaker to the smoke detector.